# Why is the remove() method in my customized LinkedList not working properly?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm sorry if this is a very long code, but the only problem is the remove() method in the LinkedList Class, and I've been struggling on this code for hours and couldn't seem to find a solution. Whenever I input ADD 456 for the main method, instead of printing

```
0+6+5+4
RESULT 15
```

I keep on getting

```
0+6+6+4
RESULT 16
```

That means either the remove() or insert() method went wrong, but when I checked the input of the insert() method, 5 was properly inserted when it had to. So I was wondering which part of the remove() method went wrong, and how I could solve it. Thanks.

These are the interfaces.

Interface Stack.

```
package ds.stack;

public interface Stack<E> {
/*
 * Removes all of the elements in this stack.
 */
public void clear();

/*
 * Pushes an item onto the top of this stack.
 * 
 * @param item
 *            the item to be pushed onto this stack
 */
public void push(E item);

/**
 * Removes the item at the top of this stack and returns that item as the
 * value of this method.
 * 
 * @return the item at the top of this stack, or null if this stack is empty
 */
public E pop();

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this stack.
 * 
 * @return the number of elements in this stack
 */
public int length();

/**
 * Returns true if this stack contains no elements.
 * 
 * @return true if this stack contains no elements
 */
public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Interface List.

```
package ds.list;

public interface List<E> {
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.
 */
public void clear();

/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
 * 
 * @param pos
 *            index at which the specified element is to be inserted
 * @param item
 *            element to be inserted
 */
public void insert(int pos, E item);

/**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any
 * subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).
 * Returns the element that was removed from the list.
 * 
 * @param pos
 *            the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element previously at the specified position
 */
public E remove(int pos);

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 * 
 * @return the number of elements in this list.
 */
public int length();

/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 * 
 * @param pos
 *            index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 */
public E getValue(int pos);
}
```

Here is my LinkedList Class

```
package ds.list;

public class LinkedList<E> implements List<E> {
private E element;
private LinkedList<E> next;
private LinkedList<E> head;
private LinkedList<E> tail;
private LinkedList<E> curr;
public int cnt=0;   //length of the list
/*
* constructors below
*/
public LinkedList() {   //The very initial constructor
    curr = tail = head = this;
}
public LinkedList(LinkedList<E> nextval) {  //when you start making more bundles
    next = nextval;
}

public void setNext(LinkedList<E> nextval) {
    next = nextval;
}

public void goNext() {
    curr = next;
}   // curr becomes the next bundle

public void setValue(E item) {
    element = item;
}
@Override
public void clear() {
    tail = head = new LinkedList<E>();
    next = null;
    cnt = 0;
}

@Override
public void insert(int pos, E item) {
    if(pos<0||pos>cnt+1) {
        return;
    }
    if(pos==0) {
        curr = head;
        head = new LinkedList<E>(curr);
        curr = head;
        curr.setValue(item);
    }
    curr = head;
    for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++) {
        goNext();
    }   //curr points right before the index of pos
    LinkedList<E> temp = curr.next;
    curr.setNext(new LinkedList<E>(temp));
    curr.goNext();
    curr.setValue(item);
    cnt++;
}

@Override
public E remove(int pos) {
    if(pos<0||pos>cnt)
        return null;
    curr = head;
    if(cnt==1) {
        E it = element;
        curr = head = tail = null;
        cnt--;
        return it;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++) {
        goNext();
    }
    E it = next.element;
    curr.setNext(next.next);
    cnt--;
    return it;
}

@Override
public int length() {
    return cnt;
}

@Override
public E getValue(int pos) {
    if(pos<0||pos>cnt)
        return null;
    curr = head;
    for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++) {
        goNext();
    }
    return next.element;
}
}
```

And this is my LinkedStack Class, utilizing the LinkedList Class

```
package ds.stack;

import ds.list.LinkedList;

public class LinkedStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
private LinkedList<E> stack = new LinkedList<E>();
@Override
public void clear() {
    stack.clear();
}

@Override
public void push(E item) {
    if(stack.cnt == 0) {
        stack.setValue(item);
        stack.cnt++;
        return;
    }
    stack.insert(stack.length(),item);
}

@Override
public E pop() {
    if(stack.length()==0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return stack.remove(stack.length()-1);
    }
}

@Override
public int length() {
    return stack.length();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(stack.length()==0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

}
```

Then this is my BabyCalculator Class that uses the LinkedStack Class

```
package ds.test;

import ds.stack.LinkedStack;
import ds.stack.Stack;

public class BabyCalculator {
Stack<Character> stack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
private int value=0;

public int murmurAdd(String polynomial) {
    char[] charPol=polynomial.toCharArray();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<polynomial.length();i++) {
        if(!(Character.isDigit(charPol[i])))
            count++;
    }   // This counts the total number of ( and )s.
    int numOf=count/2;
    if (numOf==0) {
        for(int i=0;i<polynomial.length();i++) {
            stack.push(charPol[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0;i<numOf;i++) {
            int num1=0, num2 = 0;   //will become the index of last ( and first )
            for(int j=0;j<polynomial.length();j++) {
                if(charPol[j]=='(')
                    num1 = j;
                if(charPol[j]==')') {
                    num2 = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int index=num1+1;index<num2;index++) {
                stack.push(charPol[index]);
            }
            StringBuilder polytemp = new StringBuilder(polynomial);
            polynomial=polytemp.replace(num1, num2+1, "").toString();
        }
        if(polynomial.length()>0) {
            charPol = polynomial.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<polynomial.length();i++) {
                stack.push(charPol[i]); 
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(value);
    while(!(stack.isEmpty())) {
            Character a = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(" a is "+a);
            value += Character.getNumericValue(a);
            System.out.print("+"+a); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    return value;
}

public int getValue() {
    // TODO Implement this method
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int newValue) {
    // TODO Implement this method
    value = newValue;
}
}
```

Finally, the main() method that uses BabyCalculator.

```
package ds.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BabyCalculator babyCalculator = new BabyCalculator();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String command = sc.next();
        if ("ADD".equals(command)) {
            String equation = sc.next();
            babyCalculator.murmurAdd(equation);
            System.out.println("RESULT "+babyCalculator.getValue());
            // TODO
        } else if ("SHOW".equals(command)) {
            System.out.println("VALUE "+babyCalculator.getValue());
            // TODO
        } else if ("CLEAR".equals(command)) {
            babyCalculator.setValue(0);
            System.out.println("VALUE CLEARED");
            // TODO
        } else if ("SET".equals(command)) {
            int newValue = sc.nextInt();
            babyCalculator.setValue(newValue);
            System.out.println("VALUE SET TO "+babyCalculator.getValue());
            // TODO
        } else if ("EXIT".equals(command)) {
            System.out.println("FINAL VALUE "+ babyCalculator.getValue());
            return;
            // TODO
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
}
```

EDIT : When I tried ADD (2345), the result was

```
0+5+5+5+2
RESULT 17
```

Which means 5 kept popping out only until it was time for 2 to pop out. Why does this keep happening?I'm assuming it's a deep pointing issue in LinkedList class.

Comment: Stack is your interface? What is import for Stack? I wanted to try your code but can't compile...

Comment: Oh I thought interface wasn't needed. I will import it thanks.

Comment: Seems you are working on custom interfaces. I thought it's standard JDK List.. I can't compile even that class.

Comment: Sorry I uploaded all the interfaces and the packages. Is it now compilable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can say with certainty that your `LinkedList` is not correctly implemented. You need to do unit testing of your foundational classes before you build on top of them. A basic test involving nothing more than inserting a few elements into position 0 and then trying to get the value of items in positions 0, 1, and 2 fails.

This was a basic test I wrote and it fails with `NullPointerException`.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.insert(0, "A");
list.insert(0, "B");
list.insert(0, "C");

System.out.println(list.getValue(0));
System.out.println(list.getValue(1));
System.out.println(list.getValue(2));
```

Add more logging throughout your code, use a debugger, implement `toString` methods on your classes to help you find the problems.

I can tell you that your `LinkedList` method `getValue` does not work as intended. To get my test above to work I had to change from this:

```
for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++) {
    goNext();
}
return next.element;
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    goNext();
}
return curr.element;
```

The reason is because "next" refers to the next element of whatever `LinkedList` you called `getValue` on, not the next element after the current one.

I can also tell you that you have a similar bug in your `goNext` method of `LinkedList`:

```
public void goNext() {
    curr = next;
}
```

should be:

```
public void goNext() {
    curr = curr.next;
}
```

There are almost certainly more issues with this class, so I highly recommend you thoroughly test and debug it as this will probably solve many of your problems.

Comment: Wow thank you! This was my first time programming in multiple classes so I didn't know when and how to test the validity of a class. Thank you for the tips and the explanation. Now I understand when to use 'curr.next' and just 'next'.

Comment: You're welcome. For some further reading take a look at the [JUnit Testing Framework](http://junit.org/junit5/). Writing automated tests can save you a lot of headache as you can make a change and then re-run all your tests to ensure you didn't break anything that was previously working.

Answer (score 0):

I see more issues than one. The insert is wrong, the remove is wrong (you can validate) by calling ADD twice in the same run.

One such issue is in insert I changed your code as below:

```
//LinkedList<E> temp = curr.next;
    //curr.setNext(new LinkedList<E>(temp));
    LinkedList<E> temp = new LinkedList<E>(curr.next);
    temp.setValue(curr.element);
```

And removed the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<pos-1;i++) {
    goNext();
}
```

in remove method Atleast add test works. But you have more problems at hand. I didn't test much of other usecases.